# Curator_cli V5.8 Disable logging?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

Can anyone help me to disable logging for curator_cli.
For Example , I have tried the command 
Command :

***curator_cli  --host localhost show_indices  --filter_list '[{"filtertype":"age","source":"creation_date","direction":"younger","unit":"minutes","unit_count":60,"timestring":"%Y.%m.%d"}]'***

Output : 
***2020-02-17 18:44:50,286 INFO      Instantiating client object
2020-02-17 18:44:50,287 INFO      Testing client connectivity
2020-02-17 18:44:50,290 INFO      Successfully created Elasticsearch client object with provided settings
logstash-2020.02.17***

So ,I only want ***logstash-2020.02.17*** as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curator_cli` was designed to log to stdout if no log file is specified. You could set `--logfile /dev/null` or even an actual file to get the desired result. It might even work to set `--loglevel CRITICAL` or `FATAL` to shut off the default `INFO` log level.